# Key-dependent actions using uniquingKeysWith

Tags: swift

I'm merging dictionaries which need different actions within uniquingKeysWith depending on the key value. I need the following key dependent behavior in one merge:

```
["sum":1]       + ["sum":2]       --> ["sum":3]
["accum":"A"]   + ["accum":"B"]   --> ["accum":["A", "B"]]
["negate":true] + ["negate":true] --> ["negate":false]
["first":"A"]   + ["first":"B"]   --> ["first":"A"]
["last":"A"]    + ["last":"B"]    --> ["last":"B"]
```

This of course would involve knowledge of the keys "sum", "accum", ..."last" within uniquingKeysWith, which I think is where it should be.

However the value of key doesn't seem knowable within uniquingKeysWith, and thus IMHO it seems impossible to do with the methods including uniquingKeysWith. I have restored to doing the merge by hand. Is this correct? Shouldn't this be included in future versions?

Comment: It sounds as if you should implement a class with all those properties (if you know them before, which you should, since you want to have a custom behaviour for each entry). Then you could just overload the addition (or implement a `mergeWith` function)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
class MyDict {
    let sum: Int
    let acum: [String]
    let negate: Bool
    let first: String
    let last: String

    init(sum: Int, acum: [String], negate: Bool, first: String, last: String) {
        self.sum = sum
        self.acum = acum
        self.negate = negate
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
    }
}
func +(lhs: MyDict, rhs: MyDict) -> MyDict {
    return MyDict(sum: lhs.sum + rhs.sum, acum: lhs.acum + rhs.acum,
                  negate: lhs.negate != rhs.negate, first: lhs.first, last: rhs.last)
}

let a = MyDict(sum: 1, acum: ["A"], negate: true, first: "a", last: "aa")
let b = MyDict(sum: 2, acum: ["B"], negate: true, first: "b", last: "bb")
a + b //== MyDict(sum: 3, acum: ["A","B"], negate: false, first: "a", last: "bb")
```

The only thing I don't know is what you want negate to do

Comment: Yes, that should work.  Thanks.    I guess I was hoping that I could just use hashes (with just the resolution in the uniquingKeysWith functions (if it gave access to 'key') and wouldn't have to embed key strings (e.g. "sum") as properties (e.g. .sum) of a class. Hiho